# Rational G-spectrum and geometric fixed points

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, equivariant-homotopy, rational-homotopy-theory

For a finite group $G$, how is a rational $G$-spectrum $X$ detected by the geometric fixed point functor $\phi^H$ where we consider the conjugacy class of $H\leq G$? I tried finding a reference for the same but could not. The best explanation I could find so far has been Corollary 3.4.28 from Schwede's 'Global homotopy theory':
For every finite group $G$, every orthogonal $G$-spectrum $X$ and every integer $k$ the map
$$
\left(\phi^H\circ\text{res}^G_H\right)_H:\pi^G_k(X)\longrightarrow \prod\limits_{(H)\leq G} \left(\phi^H_k(X)\right)^{W_GH}
$$
becomes an isomorphism after inverting the order of $G$.

Is it true in the category of rational $G$-spectra, there is an equivalence described by the functor?
$$
X\longmapsto\prod\limits_{(H)\leq G} \phi^H(X)
$$

Any reference and/or explanation would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This is implied by Theorem 3.10 in Wimmer's "[A model for genuine equivariant commutative ring spectra away from the group order](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.12420)". Taking $R = \Bbb Q$ and $\mathcal F$ to be the full family of subgroups of a finite group $G$, it says that the geometric fixed-point functors induce an equivalence
$$
Sp^G_{\Bbb Q} \to \prod_{[H] < G} Fun(BW_H, Sp_{\Bbb Q}).
$$
So a rational genuine $G$-spectrum $X$ is equivalent data to its collection of rational spectra $\Phi^H(X)$ equipped with their $W_H$-actions.